# ExpandableListView changes getCount() but not visually

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView that loads well the first time but then after the adapter values are changed and notifyDataSetChanged called (I even tried setting the adapter again) the  ExpandableListView on screen stays the same... however getCount() does change. Before posting the code, let me explain my intention and what I've tried so far. I want to generate the data for the adapter's variables when page 2 in the ViewPager is shown, and then show it in the ExpandableListView inside that same fragment. I managed to do this in several different ways but there's always a problem that makes me look for an alternative.

First I made all of this in the ViewPager's default class, MainActivity, using addOnPageChangeListener instead of SimpleOnPageChangeListener, and made the variables related to the ExpandableListView static, so I could set the adapter from MainActivity. The data was generated flawlessly everytime the specific page was shown, but there was a problem: the ExpandableListView wasn't showing anything, even tho all the variables involved had the correct values and the adapter was set.

So I took another road... I made the ViewPager static, put the listener for it in page 2 fragment class and generated data+set adapter from there, no static variables involved with the exception of the ViewPager. This works flawlessly for the first swipe to the page, data is generated and shown successfully, but in subsequent swipes to the page something weird happens: the code inside the listener is called x times each time, with x being the number of times the user has swiped to the fragment. This means first time it calls the code once (good), then two times second time and so on... this obviously messes up everything. I tested and this doesn't happen when the listener is in MainActivity, the code there is called only once everytime (but ExpandableListView is not showing anything). In this stage first swipe is perfect but second also delivers the expected result, updating the ExpandableListView and everything but doing so much work than necessary (because of running the code once), then at third swipe I get a NullPointerException (no surprise given the amount of messing it does).

At this point I get very frustrated, it seems everytime I use a static variable it doesn't work correctly: first with the ExpandableListView related variables used to set the adapter from MainActivity, then with making the ViewPager static and using a listener from it to run a method in another class.

Next step was reading for a substitute to addOnPageChangeListener to see if that worked, that's when I met SimpleOnPageChangeListener. I was happy, it worked... it run the code only once with every swipe to the Page while also showing the result in the ExpandableListView but, problem... it doesn't update it even tho it's data changes successfully (current stage).

So I'm kind of new with programming in general and don't have a clue of what's going on here... if it's that I'm discovering a bunch of bugs, something messed up with my installed SDK or if there's something else I'm missing. Please help.

Simplified version of my current stage:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class ResultsFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment  {

    ExpandableListView resultsELV;
    HashMap<Header,List<String>> resultsHash = new HashMap<Header, List<String>>();
    List<Header> resultsTitles = new ArrayList<>();
    ResultsAdapter resultsAdapter;

    View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_results, container, false);
        resultsELV = (ExpandableListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.expandableListVieww);

        ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener listener = new 

ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                if (position == 1) {

                    getResults();

                }
            }
        };

        MainActivity.mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(listener);

        return rootView;    }

    public void getResults() {

        // resultsHash & resultsTitles get filled

        Toast.makeText(resultsELV.getContext(),resultsHash.size()+" 

"+resultsTitles,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        resultsAdapter=new ResultsAdapter(resultsELV.getContext(),resultsHash,resultsTitles);
        resultsELV.setAdapter(resultsAdapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: post your code where you are calling notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: can you show adapter code?

Comment: @Mohit SandeepTiwari updated, please help